# Heroku - not permitted to install sendgrid addon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

Trying to install the sendgrid addon in heroku.

```
$ heroku addons:create sendgrid:starter
 ▸    The account "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com" is not permitted to install the
 ▸    sendgrid add-on at this time. If you believe this is an error please
 ▸    contact support and reference ID 352288c0-21e3-468a-8935-440897e9bcd8 when
 ▸    opening an ticket.
```

Any ideas on why I would not be permitted to install the addon?  Combed the heroku site for information but could not find anything helpful.

Comment: If the account you're logged in with is a 'collaborator' you might not have the required privileges to install add-ons. Check your role / level under the *Access* tab in your app settings.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  My role is set to 'owner'.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Is it a paid for add-on? In that case you'll need to add your card details first.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and my credit card is connected to my account, still no luck.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same issue today. I contacted heroku support and got below reply. Then it works.

> It looks like your account was flagged by our anti-spam protections by mistake. This blocked your ability to add email add-ons your apps. That happens sometimes with new accounts. I have unblocked your account.

Answer (score 0):

I was banned a few times and it's really frustrating.

**Have to contact sendgrid support and after a while they unban me.**

It's especially annoying that I can not open a support request from my account that was banned - only from a new account.
[image]